# ClasscastException android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider to action.view.ActionProvider

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

Below is my Activity Code.

The problem is that i am not able to use AppCompat library properly and its giving me

`ClasscastException android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider to action.View.ActionProvider`

```
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider shareAction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    MenuItem item =(MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings);
    shareAction = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionProvider(item);
    shareAction.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    return true;
}

public Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEST")
            .setType("text/plain");
    return share;
}

}
```

According the Guide at developer.android.com i am using the library correctly

Below is my menu file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:easyshare="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    easyshare:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    easyshare:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    />
  </menu>
```

** Edited LogCat output ** Sorry earlier i was getting the exception as given in label but seeing now i am getting this error and somehow not able to find the problem

```
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:98)
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
    10-02 02 :17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at net.mobitexter.easyshare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
    10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
     10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
     10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
     10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
     10-02 02:17:46.566: E/AndroidRuntime(896):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     10-02 02:18:02.152: I/Process(896): Sending signal. PID: 896 SIG: 9
```

**See if the manifest helps **
The below is the code of my manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.mobitexter.easyshare"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="net.mobitexter.easyshare.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @CommonsWare: `android.widget.ShareActionProvider` isn't used, is it? I can only see `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider` here - so it's probably not a duplicate.

Comment: "android.widget.ShareActionProvider isn't used, is it?" -- since the OP claims that it is the error, it must be used. Unfortunately, the OP did not post a complete stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I agree, it's a good guess - for sure. However, I can't see any evidence. Don't mind ... :)

Comment: @CommonsWare  Could u help me regarding this. because i am getting nowhere with the problem

Comment: hey, try here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html This is the standard sample from google in case of v7 actioncompat.

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the cast of ShareActionProvider like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
MenuItem item =(MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings);
shareAction = (android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
shareAction.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
return true;
}
```

It should be work correctly. Please Test it and tell me if it work correctly.

Comment: No it didnt. Same error

Comment: i have edited my code you can see the difference and try it.

Comment: @Saklos- It wont work. There is a cast exception from ActionProvider to ShareActionProvider .Moreover the `item.getActionProvider` works in API 14 and above.API 14 and above is not the problem the problem is to to support Android 2.1 and above

Comment: thank you for th einformation so in this case you cant use SharlockAction bar it will be help u  http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Actually I cant use because this code is part of something big so i cannot use ActionbarSherlock (something big doesnot uses Sherlock)

Comment: this is false men, it's depend from your competance of architechture